Connectivity between MOXA and S20 Reason
I want to connect MOXA SWITCH ED510E with MOXA SFP-1GLXLC-T 1310nm to S20 Reason Managed switch with SFP AXCEN AXFD-1314-0w23 1310nm but when I connected both there is no communication also on MOXA switch Receiving Power in dBm is not showing.
the link connected between both switch down
Possible reason maybe
. SFP problem range or compatibility
. VLAN and port configurations
. STP Configurations
Kindly asking your support.

Has any answer solved your question? Then please accept it or your question will keep popping up here forever. Please also consider voting for useful answers.

If you compare the datasheets:

AXFD-1314-0w23: IEEE802.3ah 100BASE-LX10 compatible
SFP-1GLXLC-T: 1000BaseLX

Those are not compatible speed-wise. You need to use SFPs that support a common speed. Most transceivers are single speed.

on MOXA switch Receiving Power in dBm is not showing

That might indicate yet another problem with wavelengths on both sides matching - possibly unsuitable fiber type, excessive length, a broken link or an uncrossed (patch) cable. Or it might just indicate that the Moxa switch doesn't show anything with the link down.
